# Geolocation-based, wireless mesh routing algorithm: useful?

Tags: networking, ip-address, network-protocols, wireless, mesh-network

I'm in a team and we are supposed to be setting up a 'geolocation-based', ipv6, wifi mesh network to run on google android.

The idea is to use the geolocation (latitude, longitude, altitude) of each node to generate the IPv6 address, then use that to choose the closest node as the preferred node for routing through. Some optimisation is made through periodic 'routing load' messages.

http://www.v6pc.jp/apc/en/data/addressing.pdf

My understanding is:
The main 'benefit' of doing a geolocation-based algorithm is that each network hop will step physically closer to the destination... and we *assume* that travelling in the most direct path to the destination, is going to give us the most optimal routing path.

BUT, my problem with this approach is that physical proximity + load does not necessarily imply good connection strength or fast routing. What if there's a thick lead wall(?) or lots of interference?

Surely proximity is a fairly useless metric for determining routes?

The primary metrics should be primarily based on performance/load, shouldn't they? Something like signal strength, demonstrated throughput, CPU usage, time connected to the network, etc. At least that was my understanding of how routing paths should be chosen.

Why is this a good idea? Is there something I'm missing?

I haven't spent a lot of time working with networks, so please put in noobman's terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three main paramaters for any connection are bandwidth, latency and capacity. Bandwidth would be measured in bytes per second, latency in milliseconds, and capacity in % of bandwidth used. Those are all parameters you can determine for connections to neighboring nodes (Before you join the mesh, capacity used will likely be 0%)

You need capacity because you want to avoid congested nodes even if they would have good bandwidth and latency.

Comment: Can you see -any- benefit in a proximity based algorithm?

Comment: @secoif: Like you said, close proximity does not indicate best performance. I would use it as a first-stage filter but then use the bandwidth, etc., as MSalters mentioned to zero in on the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I'm missing?

Yes, so far as I can tell there's no IPv6 support in Android yet...

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but more of a list of postulations, as this is the first place I have seen anyone talking about this.

I have pondered geolocation mesh networking for some time, as a method to reduce the "flood" problem.
I have 2 more ideas to help with the issue about node desirability. The second one is a bit more harebrained ..

1. nodes keep 'reputation' scores for the nodes they connect to. This would require that after a packet is sent on a performance response would need to be sent back to the node that sent it.
   1a). Reputations should be maintained by the nodes around a target node, the target node should have no way to alter what the surrounding nodes judge about its reputation.
   1b). The performance reports, used to judge reputation, would need to be relayed back from the node that the target node forwarded the packet to. This report would need to be encrypted in such a way that it could be understood by the originating node, but not altered by the target node.
2. Crazy idea to try to encourage the upkeep of nodes. Attach crypto-currency payments at a fixed value for each bit of data handled by a node. The faster that a node can relay data, the more money it makes.

Other thoughts on geolocated mesh networking involves the directory system. This is not a well considered thought yet, but:

1. We live in a finite universe, things can only go so fast. It is obvious that a system needs to be maintained by every node to keep a directory of all end nodes in the network, so that an end node may address traffic to/from another end node. In a geolocated mesh backbone, that information is not required between the router nodes, as they should be in fixed locations. But it is needed for end nodes, which move, as governed by physical law.
   1a) That being understood, and end node needs to register itself with the router nodes it can connect to. In close proximity that registration needs to be maintained with pretty fine granularity. Similar to how cell tower hand-offs are handled.
   2a) But as distance from an end node increases the updates may become less frequent, and more generalized, until they become little more than north,south,east,west (I am not sure up/down would even be need to be registered for terrestrial communications). The regional circumference would probably need to be determined by the end node's speed. Maybe the rate at which it connects to new router nodes could determine that.

And lastly. it would be wonderful if geolocated mesh routing could be tied to a non-terrestrial origin point, maybe a point in distant space that is for all intensive purposes is fixed for the foreseeable future. This would require some means for nodes to constantly offset their positions from that point using orbital mathematics.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30095329)